# Show Yoast's keywords in source?

Tags: wordpress, seo

How do I get Yoast to include keywords in the source? I have keywords filled out on each page along with a description. On my pages, the description shows but they keyword line doesn't. I have the keyword box checked in the Yoast settings.

```
<!-- This site is optimized with the Yoast WordPress SEO plugin v1.4.7 - http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/ -->
<title>TITLE</title>
<meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION"/>
<meta property='og:locale' content='en_US'/>
<meta property='og:type' content='article'/>
<meta property='og:title' content='title'/>
<meta property='og:description' content='description'/>
<meta property='og:url' content='URL'/>
<meta property='og:site_name' content='Site Name'/>
<meta property='og:image' content='image'/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="twitter"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Description"/>
<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->
```

(I removed the title/description/url's from the code above.)

Comment: You should probably contact Yoast himself, or use the support forum on the wordpress site.  Although I simply wouldn't use the meta keywords, they have zero use.

Answer (score 0):

yoasts seo plugin doesnt generate a meta keyword in your HTML code. 
Read this http://yoast.com/meta-keywords/ ;)